# Storing unencrypted web app / WordPress passwords - explain to a client

Tags: permissions, database, wordpress, password

I have a problem with a client who is complaining about a WordPress installation having an unencrypted MySQL database password in the `wp-config.php` file.

I've tried explaining this to him by stating that this is a standard procedure and whoever is able to read the contents of that file, would have had administrative privileges regardless and that the database should also be protected by restricting hosts that can connect to it.

The client is very stubborn and claims that "We have higher security than that on our Intranet, which is much better shielded."

Are there any other arguments for or against storing database credentials in plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, the password *must* be unencrypted in that particular configuration file because it needs to be read in order to authenticate to the database.

However, it's possible to use no password by giving the proper permissions and appropriate hostname restrictions, but I do not recommend this as anyone with access to the server can use `mysql` to access the protected database.

The password can only be accessed by someone with shell access to the server, so it's not a problem in the grand scheme of things. Further, the database server shouldn't be accessible from the web. If it's a problem, then it's a policy issue, not IT.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense and while encrypting the password is possible, it doesn't seem like it would be of any extra security value.

Comment: That's right. Even if you encrypted it, you'd need to put the decryption method somewhere that Wordpress can use it (by modifying code, for example) rendering this moot.